# Convert String Field to Date value in a different format with an SQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column start_date. Unfortunately, the datatype of the column is VARCHAR. Values in this column are either null or a string date in any format.

I have a requirement to extract the data from this table to a CSV file using BCP command. But while extracting, start_date value is expected to be in YYYYMMDD format in the output file.

The problem here is for some records, start_Date will be in DD/MM/YYYY format and for some others it may be in another format. For example : YYYY-MM-DD.

Is there any way so that I can convert the start_date value to the format YYYYMMDD irrespective of the actual format using the select query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!!

```
select
    *,
    (CASE WHEN [Date] like '%/%' then TRY_CONVERT(datetime,[Date],103)
    else [Date] END) as [New_DATE]    
from TableName;
```

Comment: This won't work if the input column date is in YYYYMMDD Format

Comment: This query is working for me for the case  YYMMDD as well.

Comment: Sorry friend. Working fine for YYYYMMDD format. But not working for dates in format MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: select *,
(case when left(date,2) between 01 and 12 then TRY_CONVERT(datetime,DATE,101) 
 end) as new_date from testfile
--This will work for mm-dd-yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy format

Answer (score 0):

`select convert(DATE,'13/12/2019',112) as 'AliasName'`

This function will help u in fetching the data in the format of YYYYMMDD irrespective of how the format of ur input column is..This function uses 3 arguments 1.THE DATA TYPE WHICH U WANT TO CONVERT 2. YOUR INPUT COLUMN WHICH U WANT TO CONVERT 3.STYLE (style number is: Each format has its own style number for example if you give style number as 103 it will convert to dd/mm/yyyy  or if 112 it will convert to YYYYMMDD ..there are many style You will find it if u search about convert function) . Hope this will help!

Comment: This is not working. I am getting the below error in this case : The input character string does not follow style 112, either change the input character string or use a different style.

Comment: Kindly refer this http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: I guess using DATETIME instead of date will help , even if it returns time value, we can  use substring over it